# SAS, Make my macro function conditional based on the number of variables input

Tags: macros, sas

For example, I want to create a macro for sort function.

```
%MACRO sort(a,via,b);
proc sort data=&a out=&b;
    by &via;
run;
%MEND;

%sort(presort,variable,postsort);
```

But if I want this macro do the following code

```
proc sort data=presort;
    by variable;
run;
```

as well by typing

```
%sort(presort,variable);
```

How can I realize that?

Please notice that I used three variables for the first, and two for the second.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, but I hope you've just given a simple example above, and you're not actually thinking about creating a 'wrapper' macro for proc sort.  Creating wrapper macros are a very bad idea as they limit re-usability (you may not be able to take them with you to your next job), add complexity for no significant gain (it doesn't do anything in addition to what proc sort already does), make it harder for others to read your code, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You are not forced to use positional parameters in a macro definition.  Instead use named parameters.  Named parameters can have default values.

```
%macro sort(in,byvars,out=&in);
   proc sort data=&in out=&out ;
      by &byvars ;
   run;
%mend sort ;
```

Since the first two parameters are positional you can call them without naming them.

```
%sort(presort,var1 var2 var3);
%sort(presort,var1 var2 var3,out=postsort);
```

But you can also call them by name if you want.

```
%sort(out=postsort,in=presort,byvars=var1 var2 var3)
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS does not support overloading of macro functions.  The SAS way to do this is to make the 3rd parameter optional.

```
%macro sort(a,via,b=);

proc sort data=&a
   %if "&b" ^= "" %then %do;
       out=&b
   %end;
   ;
by &via;
run;

%mend;

data test;
do i=1 to 10;
    r = rannor(0);
    output;
end;
run;

%sort(test,r,b=testout);
%sort(test,r);
```